# Javascript function doesn't appear to run?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to call a function from an image in my HTML, wondering if anyone could shed some light on why the function does not appear to be running?

```js
function markAnswers() {
  var intCorrect = 0;
  if document.getElementById('question1').value.toUpperCase() = "GROUNDHOG DAY" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
  }

  if document.getElementById('question2').value.toUpperCase() = "CAMERON DIAZ" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
  }

  if document.getElementById('question3').value.toUpperCase() = "BLADE RUNNER" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
  }

  if document.getElementById('question4').value.toUpperCase() = "THE AVENGERS" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
  }

  if document.getElementById('question5').value.toUpperCase() = "WHOOPI GOLDBERG" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
  }

  switch (correct) {
    case 0:
      alert("You scored 0/5! You weren't even trying!");
      break;
    case 1:
      alert("You scored 1/5! Come on you can do better than that!");
      break;
    case 2:
      alert("You scored 2/5! Well at least you got a couple right!");
      break;
    case 3:
      alert("You scored 3/5! Average...");
      break;
    case 4:
      alert("You scored 4/5! Not bad... Not bad at all!");
      break;
    case 5:
      alert("You scored 5/5!! Perfection!");
      break;
    default:
      alert("Ermm... something went wrong. Well this is awkward.");
  }
}
```

```css
.submitbtn {
  background-image: url('../images/markup.png');
  width: 221px;
  height: 39px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.submitbtn:hover {
  background-image: url('../images/markdown.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <form>
    <h3>DOUGHY DRAGON</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">GROUNDHOG DAY</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question1" name="q1" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>CORN MAIZE AD</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">CAMERON DIAZ</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question2" name="q2" placeholder="Actress">
    <br>
    <h3>NEAR BLUNDER</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">BLADE RUNNER</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question3" name="q3" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>SEVENTH GEAR</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">THE AVENGERS</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question4" name="q4" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>WORD BOGGLE IHOP</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">WHOOPI GOLDBERG</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question5" name="q5" placeholder="Actress">
    <br>
  </form>
  <div class="submitbtn" id="submitbutton" onclick="markAnswers()"></div>
</div>
```

I thought the `onclick="markAnswers()"` should call this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please sort out the indentation - thanks

Comment: Why is there nothing in your button `div`? We can't actually click it

Comment: 'correct' variable is not initialized in your shared code.

Comment: Try giving a `&nbsp;` at least within your div and then try again.

Comment: @blint the image isn't showing up, OP should add `background-color: red` or something similar to `submitbtn`

Comment: `var intCorrect = 0` is declared, but afterwards you use `correct` instead. This should get picked up by the browser's error console, BTW.

Comment: Please do not submit code which has syntax errors. View your console to find and then fix those errors. If you don't know what the "console" is, please learn about it right away. It turns out that your computer can find syntax errors MUCH faster than the folks here at SO, so you can fix them right away and get on with your work.

Comment: You have a lot of code duplication. That's bad ok.
`var answers = ['blah'...];
var messages = ['blah'...];

function markAnswers() {
    var result = answers.reduce(function(result, ans, i){
         return result + (document.getElementById('question' + (++i)).value.toUpperCase() === ans);   
    }, 0);;
    
    alert("You scored " + result + "/" + answers.length + "! " + messages[result]);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do check your conditional statements properly:

```
if (document.getElementById('question1').value.toUpperCase() == "GROUNDHOG DAY"){
    correct = (correct +1);
}
```

instead of:

```
if document.getElementById('question1').value.toUpperCase() = "GROUNDHOG DAY"{
    correct = (correct +1);
}
```

You did not wrap the conditions with open close brackets `(` and `)` and it should be `==` instead of `=`

And your variable `correct` is not defined

Comment: Personally I am not too excited about the idea of answering questions involving error-ridden code, which ends up promoting use of SO as a sort of crowd-sourced typo-spotting service, and fails to encourage users to learn the rudiments of syntax and debugging themselves. Also, it seems weird to give typos and syntax errors as an "answer" when they have already earlier been pointed out in the comments, which IMHO is the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are messing around with a form submit button and a clickable div.
If you want to keep your div, then remove the `onclick` attribute from your div as follows :

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <form>
    <h3>DOUGHY DRAGON</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">GROUNDHOG DAY</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question1" name="q1" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>CORN MAIZE AD</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">CAMERON DIAZ</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question2" name="q2" placeholder="Actress">
    <br>
    <h3>NEAR BLUNDER</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">BLADE RUNNER</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question3" name="q3" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>SEVENTH GEAR</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">THE AVENGERS</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question4" name="q4" placeholder="Movie - 2 Words">
    <br>
    <h3>WORD BOGGLE IHOP</h3>
    <h3 class="answers">WHOOPI GOLDBERG</h3> 
    <input type="text" id="question5" name="q5" placeholder="Actress">
    <br>
  </form>
  <div class="submitbtn" id="submitbutton"></div>
</div>
```

Then change your Javascript file as follows :

```js
function markAnswers() {
var correct= 0;
if (document.getElementById('question1').value.toUpperCase() == "GROUNDHOG DAY") {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}

if (document.getElementById('question2').value.toUpperCase() == "CAMERON DIAZ") {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}

if (document.getElementById('question3').value.toUpperCase() == "BLADE RUNNER") {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}

if (document.getElementById('question4').value.toUpperCase() == "THE AVENGERS") {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}

if (document.getElementById('question5').value.toUpperCase() == "WHOOPI GOLDBERG") {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}

switch (correct) {
    case 0:
        alert("You scored 0/5! You weren't even trying!");
        break;
    case 1:
        alert("You scored 1/5! Come on you can do better than that!");
        break;
    case 2:
        alert("You scored 2/5! Well at least you got a couple right!");
        break;
    case 3:
        alert("You scored 3/5! Average...");
        break;
    case 4:
        alert("You scored 4/5! Not bad... Not bad at all!");
        break;
    case 5:
        alert("You scored 5/5!! Perfection!");
        break;
    default:
  

      alert("Ermm... something went wrong. Well this is awkward.");
    }
}
var clickableDiv = documentgetElementById('submitbutton');

clickableDiv.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventdefault();
    markAnswers();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors in your function:

- The if statement is written wrong
- The `correct` variable is not defined

Checkout this demo which has correction of your code:

http://jsbin.com/fihacawosa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your function markAnswers() is not executing because the code syntax is wrong.

When writing a JavaScript condition it should be written as follows:

```
if (condition) {
   ....
}
```

While equality condition should be written as :  a === b OR a == b

In your quesiton you have written a = b which means put variable b inside a

in your case : you are missing brackets and missing an equality sign

**Original Question:**
    if document.getElementById('question3').value.toUpperCase() = "BLADE RUNNER" {
        correct = (correct + 1);
    }

**The correct condition should be written as follows:**

```
if (document.getElementById('question3').value.toUpperCase()) == "BLADE RUNNER" {
    correct = (correct + 1);
}
```